# Overwriting a function in a class in PHP

Tags: php, class, oop

So I have a function in a PHP class, and I would like to have a modified version of that function for another class (an extended class).

Would I just recreate the class with my modifications inside the extended class? How would I go about having a function that acts differently in my extended class?

Comment: Because in the original class, the function is supposed to work a certain way. In the extended class, I want a slightly different, but mostly similar functionality.

Comment: @User016 It's a pretty common need to overwrite functions in OOP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override methods in child classes like this:

```
<?php

class A {
    public function printText($param) {
        echo 'foo';
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function printText($param) {
        // Optional: This will call the printText method from the parent class A
        parent::printText($param); 

        echo 'bar';
    }
}

$instanceA = new A();
$instanceA->printText('sampleArg'); // Result: foo

$instanceB = new B();
$instanceB->printText('sampleArg'); // Result: foobar

/* EOF */
```

Important is, that the overridden method has the same amount of parameters as the parent class method else you get a PHP error.

Comment: So class B would only output 'bar' then?

Comment: Yep only `bar`. You can call the parent method in the child method too. With `parent::printText('blah')` and the method `B::printText` prints `foobar`;